# Write Python List to Excel rows using xlwt

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlwt

I would like to write each value in a Python list to a new row in an Excel cell. The object I am generating the list from does not support indexing which is giving me an issue. If my list only generates one value, then there is no problem, however when I generate multiple values, I get multiple errors. I am a Python beginner using 64 bit OS X and Python 2.7. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    import mlbgame
    month = mlbgame.games(2016, 7, 21, home ="Pirates")
    games = mlbgame.combine_games(month)
    for game in games:
        print(game)

    import xlwt
    from datetime import datetime

    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    ws = wb.add_sheet('PiratesG')

    for game in games:
        ws.write(0, 0, str(game))
       #ws.write(1, 0, str(game[1]))

    wb.save('Pirates.xls')

    Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/Max/Code/PiratesGameToExcel.py", line 14, in <module>
        ws.write(0, 0, str(game))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Worksheet.py", line 1088, in write
        self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Row.py", line 241, in write
        StrCell(self.__idx, col, style_index, self.__parent_wb.add_str(label))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Row.py", line 160, in insert_cell
        raise Exception(msg)
    Exception: Attempt to overwrite cell: sheetname=u'PiratesG' rowx=0 colx=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerate()` to get the index of the list. Then you can write to successive rows like so:

```
for i,game in enumerate(games):
    ws.write(i,0,str(game))
```

Comment: Cheers, mate. Happy coding to you!